# How do I change the contribution type for a contribution that was made before 1/1/1996?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contributions, date-preferences

We're on Civi 4.6.17 and Drupal 7.

We have historic data that was imported from a previous system. There are some Contributions of type Member Dues that I want to change to a different Contribution Type - [Organization Name] Contribution - because the Contribution was misclassified when originally entered or imported.

But, the contribution was made before 1/1/1996. When I Edit the Contribution type a message pops up to "Please enter a date between 01/01/1996 and 12/31/2026".

Is the only way around this to go in to the back-end MySQL table for Contributions and change the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date Preferences at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?reset=1 can be edited so the 'offset' is greater than 20 (years)

SO you can edit Date for activities (including contributions: receive, receipt, cancel. membership: join, start, renew. case: start, end.) and set it to have years going back further than 1996 (ie 20 years)

Comment: 1996 being 20 years ago makes me feel really old!

Comment: Does 1966 being 50 years ago make you feel better?